# Custom SerializationInfo

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I'm trying to think of the best way to implement SerializationInfo GetDouble(string value) but return a BigInteger instead. I'm working with very large numbers and need a suitable way to customize the sealed class to achieve my functionality.

I'm probably overthinking it, any suggestions?

Cheers.

Comment: What about an extention method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetValue` accepts a `Type` object, and `BigInteger` has `SerializableAttribute`.